# How to convert abbreviated letters to their full words using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of test scenarios whose output should result the same no matter of what the input string is.

Input:
scenarios:

```
Test 2019
T2019
```

Output:

```
Test 2019
```

Similarly there are other scenarios like:

```
W2019 // output shd be Website
H2020 // shd result in Home2020
Su2000 // shd result in Summer2000
```

so far I have:

```
function getValue(value) {
    var letter = value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
    var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
return (
  <div style="text-transform: capitalize">{letter}</div>
 <div>{number}</div>
)

}

console.log(getValue("2000 Website"));
```

I'm able to get the first letter capitalize, however not sure the best way to transform the abbreviated letter to the full word in the examples described above.

any idea?

Comment: Do you have some sort of dictionary, or how would your program know, that "H" should convert to "Home"?

Comment: @ Ludovit Mydla: yes, so there are 4 letters and 4 words  F => Fall, Su=> Summer, S=> Spring, W=> Winter, thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you have only four options to match full word, followed by a number, I would use simple `Map` or you can even use plain JS object to map your abbreviations with dictionary words.

```js
let input = "S2019";

const MAPPING = new Map();
MAPPING.set("S", "Spring");
MAPPING.set("Su", "Summer");
MAPPING.set("F", "Fall");
MAPPING.set("W", "Winter");

function getValue(value) {
    
    let regex = /([a-z]+)(\d+)/gi;
    let result = regex.exec(value);
    if(MAPPING.has(result[1])) return `${MAPPING.get(result[1])} ${result[2]}`
    else return value;
}

console.log(getValue(input));
```